# Token works in Dev but not Prod. EDAMSystemException AuthenticationToken

Tags: php, evernote

I am having trouble getting my app to work in production environment.

First of all I created API credentials and used them to authenticate my website on Evernote sandbox.. I only need to grab some notes, not creating a web service as such so I'm assuming dev token will suffice?

I've generated a dev token and now using it to connect to the client. All is working great on dev.

I have now moved to production and had Evernote move my API credentials to their live servers... As with sandbox I generated a new dev token on my account and also authenticated my site on my live account.

However, whenever I try to return some notes through their PHP Cloud SDK I get the following error:

```
EDAMSystemException in UserStore.php line 3210:
authenticationToken
```

Here is my code I am using to call the API:

```
$this->client = new Client($token);
$note = $this->client->getNote($this->request->guid); // note guid
```

Then I can do stuff like `$note->title` - this works great in dev, just not production.

Token looks like this:

`S=s123:U=4567ab1:E=12ecf234a67:C=2345678fa58:P=1cd:A=en-devtoken:V=2:H=12adf1b71184568a7434e1a966g0b1d1`

(not my real token)

The token was generated from my live Evernote account.

Thanks

Comment: A bit confused - sorry. For production, are you using your Developer Token, or are you using an API consumer key and secret (via oauth)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it myself by providing the rest of the arguments to the Client method.

Looking into SDK code Client.php:

`public function __construct($token = null, $sandbox = true, $advancedClient = null, LoggerInterface $logger = null, $china = false)`

Everything has default values so I guess any work I was doing over use the live account was being forced back into sandbox here.

`\Client($token, false, null, null, false)` fixed the issue.

I probably should have looked in to it a little deeper but Evernotes dev docs are shockingly poor.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're doing everything right...
What I can suggest is to double-check that you don't have extra characters in your PHP string (a space for example).

If you're sure your token is right, you may want to contact evernote support and ask them to check your credentials.

It might be an error on their side.